# PHP. Cannot read a key with zero suffix

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array of items

```
$items['list'] = 

    Array
    (
        [item_0] => Array
            (
                [name] => aaa
                [lvl] => 1
            )

        [item_1] => Array
            (
                [name] => bbb
                [lvl] => 1
            )

        [item_2] => Array
            (
                [name] => ccc
                [lvl] => 1
            )
```

I can print it, but when im trying to print

```
print_r($items['list']['item_0']);
```

I get an error `Notice: Undefined index: item_0` 

Is there something special about the zero suffix?

The rest of the keys work fine.

and if I do

```
$a = array_keys($items['list']);

var_dump($a[0]);
```

It says it's a string with 9 characters.

```
string(9) "item_0"
```

---

The issue comes when i open the file in windows notepad and save it. The notepad's UTF-8 is UTF-8 BOM, which adds characters to the string.

---

I would vote to delete the quastion, as the issue is caused by unneeded actions which change encoding. Sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: Seems to work for me. http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/35c87e685ba61b5b508dafa818aff9788fcc687d

Comment: im saving the keys to a file, then reading from it. Maybe something with encoding. Using XAMP at localhost.

Comment: As long as you're reading in back into the same structure then it shouldn't matter how the array is created.

Comment: thanks for checking it. I will try to update xamp to last version

Answer (score 2):

Most likely there is a special character in there.
It could be a new line character or a invisible character.

A fix is to foreach the array and create a new array with correct characters.

```
$i = 0;
foreach($items['list'] as $val){
    $new["item_" . $i] = $val;
    $i++;
}
```

---

Other possible solution is to use the key but trim it. That could remove extra characters.

```
foreach($items['list'] as $key => $val){
    $new[trim($key)] = $val;
}
```

---

Since OP keeps refusing to answer my questions I add a guess answer.
Use preg_grep to grab the key names based on what characters is allowed.

I follow the example I got in the question which means a-Z 0-9 and underscore.
If more is needed then it can easily be added.

```
//Match key names
$keys = preg_grep("/[a-zA-Z0-9_]+/", array_keys($items['list']));
// Use array_combine to overwrite the current keys.
$items['list'] = array_combine($keys, $items['list']);
```

Comment: not sure how the extra characters got there, removed the item, remade it and it worked :/ your answer doesnt help in my case as i have random numbers in random order.

Comment: @LeoTahk in that case try the updated version. It will trim() the key. I can probably make a third version of this doesn't work. But then I need to know better the keys you have. Are they always "item_x"?

Comment: now i get 21 characters on a 11 characters string.. i need to filter all my data :/ its not just zero. Its not empty spaces, everything is trimmed and new lines removed. Probably some multibyte utf characters.

Comment: the problem is windows utf 16 versus php utf 8 i think, trying to filter my $_REQUEST now :/

Comment: @LeoTahk just answer my question instead! What are the limits of the key names?

Comment: 150 characters atm. I get multibyte characters from reading windows files.